# Prefect: How to Make a Worker Activate a Flow Specific venv Before Flow Run?

Tags: prefect

Preface: this GitHub issue is [semi-related](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/7379)

I’m wondering what the correct method would be to associate a `flow` with a `venv` so that all `flow run`s are ran in the `venv`. I’m using a [prefect worker and work pool](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/concepts/work-pools/) to execute and hold flows, respectively.

My impression from reading through some GitHub issues is that it’s better to create a `venv` ahead of time with all flow dependancies installed, then run `prefect worker start` from inside the `venv`. This approach is unfavorable because:

- it requires that flows are organized into work pools based on having compatible library dependancies.
- Or, it would require that work pools and workers have a one to one relationship with flows, to avoid needing to match flows based on dependencies.
- And in either case, workers must be built with knowledge of these dependencies ahead of time.

If this isn’t the best architecture please correct my approach, but I’m looking for a way to have flows share a one to one relationship with virtual environments. This could be accomplished by having a worker `git pull` the latest flow code, execute `python3 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate`, and finally `pip install -r requirements.txt` before running the flow. Even better would be a way to cache the `requirements.txt` file and only re-create the `venv` if the `requirements.txt` file changed.

I’ve looked into using the work pool `working directory` and `command` [configurations](https://imgur.com/a/AaVJiRA). Unfortunately, there doesn’t seem to be a manner of getting the worker inside the flow’s project directory so that `requirements.txt` can be referenced by the command prior to running the flow.

Im at this point stuck. What’s the optimal way of handling dependancies for flows with prefect? Must `workers` be pre-built with knowledge of all their assigned work pool’s flow’s dependancies, and flows organized into work pools based on having compatible dependancies?

For reference, I’m booting the worker as a docker container. Flow code is hosted remotely in a git repository, and the worker can `git clone` the repo prior to every run as it stands.